# Drools Kie Server ignoring AgendaFilter

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server, drools-kie-workbench

I've two guided decision tables in one project. My requirement is to execute only those rules which belong to one decision table at any given point of time. I tried to use RuleNameEndsWithAgendaFilter("some suffix") with FireAllRulesCommand class but Kie server is not filtering the rules based on the passed AgendaFilter. It runs all the rules every time.

Drools Workbench version 7.2.0.Final and Drools Kie Server version 7.2.0.Final.

Below is the code snippet for the same:

```
KieServicesConfiguration configuration = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(serverUrl, user, password);
Set<Class<?>> allClasses = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
allClasses.add(OrderItem.class);
configuration.addExtraClasses(allClasses);
configuration.setMarshallingFormat(MarshallingFormat.JAXB);

OrderItem oi = new OrderItem("Mobile", 7000.00, 0.00, "");

KieServicesClient client = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(configuration);

// work with rules
List<ExecutableCommand<?>> commands = new ArrayList<ExecutableCommand<?>>();
BatchExecutionCommandImpl executionCommand = new BatchExecutionCommandImpl(commands, "defaultKieSession");

InsertObjectCommand insertObjectCommand = new InsertObjectCommand();
insertObjectCommand.setOutIdentifier("orderItem");
insertObjectCommand.setObject(oi);

FireAllRulesCommand fireAllRulesCommand = new FireAllRulesCommand();
fireAllRulesCommand.setAgendaFilter(new RuleNameEndsWithAgendaFilter("MyRuleSuffix", true));

commands.add(insertObjectCommand);
commands.add(fireAllRulesCommand);

RuleServicesClient ruleClient = client.getServicesClient(RuleServicesClient.class);

ServiceResponse<String> response = ruleClient.executeCommands(containerId, executionCommand);
System.out.println(response.getResult());
```

Comment: How can one tell whether this is correct or not unless you provide the code of the agenda filter? Also, the top lines of your rules table, perhaps as a CSV text.

Comment: It is the default implementation comes with drools-core jar (version: 7.2.0.Final)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the standard class `RuleNameEndsWithAgendaFilter` for filtering the rules of a decision table because rules from one table  don't have equal endings.

Try `RuleNameStartsWithAgendaFilter`, possibly after renaming your tables.

Comment: In my case, RuleNameEndsWithAgendaFilter should work as my rule names are like, "Row 1 MyProject", "Row 2 MyProject", "Row 3 MyProject" .. "Row n MyProject". So, RuleNameEndsWithAgendaFilter("MyProject") should work.

Comment: Well, if you know everything better, why do you ask questions? -- Have you tried to print the actual rule names in a modified version of `RuleNameEndsWithAgendaFilter`? - There's no telling what the text of that rule table really looks like, and how the rule names are produced.